# Why is an html namespace being specified?

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, xml-namespaces

I am furthering my understanding of CSS by studying Mozilla's code for Firefox.

In `browser.css`, the code reads:

```css
.ac-tags-text[selected] > html|span.ac-tag {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  color: hsl(210, 80%, 40%);
}

html|span.ac-emphasize-text-title,
html|span.ac-emphasize-text-tag,
html|span.ac-emphasize-text-url {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Repeatedly, `html|span` is used instead of just `span`.

What other namespace is being protected by specifying the `html` namespace?

If specifying the namespace is needed, why is it not specified everywhere in the CSS code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "everywhere"?

Answer (score 4):

> What other namespace is being protected by specifying the `html` namespace?

If you're asking what the default namespace in browser.css is, it is the XUL namespace. You can find the namespace declarations where you would normally expect them — near the top of the stylesheet:

```css
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
@namespace html url("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
@namespace svg url("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
```

Since the default namespace is XUL, not HTML, all type selectors matching HTML elements must contain the `html|` namespace prefix, otherwise they'll attempt to match elements in the default namespace instead.

> If specifying the namespace is needed, why is it not specified everywhere in the CSS code?

If you're asking why it's not specified for things like the `[selected]` attribute selector, it's because that attribute (along with a number of others) is part of the default namespace, *not* the HTML namespace.

If you're asking why it's not specified for things like the `.ac-tags-text` class selector, remember that compound selectors without an explicit type selector or universal selector are accompanied by an implicit `*`. Recall from one of your previous questions,

[What is the difference between * and *|* in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987370/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-css)

that when a default namespace is specified, `*` matches elements of any type *only in the default namespace*. This prevents elements outside the default namespace (like HTML and SVG elements) from matching the selector even if they happen to have the same class name.